# ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'XYZ.app/abc.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Abcbundle' is not permitted

Tags: ios, frameworks, app-store

ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'abcd .app/xyz.bundle/Contents/MacOS/xyzBundle' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure."

I am using Mac OS bundle in my project as a Framework use.
Its running perfectly in iOS Device as well as in Simulator but when I try to upload the app on app store its giving me the above error.

Please give me suggestion.

Comment: The error message from iTunes store clearly states that you are trying to upload binary for MacOS.. You need to set BaseSDK to latest iOS present in Build Settings of your Target.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found my answer from so much digging. I have used Mac OS bundle and for iOS app. That needs to be compatible for iOS app.

Go to Target -> Build Settings and
Just change Base SDK from **macOS** to **Latest iOS**.
Also change **Skip Install** to **NO**